# jQuery if has() selector do stuff

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
<ul id="bad-drifting">
    <li>text</li>
</ul>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/wZ8MC/2/

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() { 
    if (jQuery('#bad-drifting').has('em')) {
        jQuery('#bad-drifting').css({'color': 'red'});
        jQuery('#bad-drifting').css({'font-weight': 'bold'});
    }
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/Xzn6y/

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() { 
    if (jQuery('#bad-drifting li:has(em)')) { // .has('em')
        jQuery('#bad-drifting').css({'color': 'red'});
        jQuery('#bad-drifting').css({'font-weight': 'bold'});
    }
});
```

What I want to do is not just set some CSS but make more complicated changes but I can't figure out why this always returns true... Is it a bug or what am I missing?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

That's because `has` returns a jQuery object and an object is a truthy value in JavaScript, you should use `length` property:

```
if (jQuery('#bad-drifting').has('em').length) {
```

Comment: You'd think a function called has() would return true or false.. thanks though!

Comment: what is the point with .has() function then as .children('em') would be the same

Comment: @OZZIE No, they don't do the same thing. `has` filters the current collection, whereas `children` searches and optionally filters children of the current collection.

Answer (score 1):

You need to check for `length` because `jQuery('#bad-drifting li:has(em)')` returns a jQuery object which will be always truthy.

```
if (jQuery('#bad-drifting li:has(em)').length) { // .has('em')
```

Answer (score 0):

```
if (jQuery('#bad-drifting').has('em')[0]) { // do Stuff
```

Answer (score 0):

I ended up doing like this:

```
if (jQuery('#bad-drifting em').length > 0) {
    console.log('we have some errors');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Check the length of your jQuery "collection":

```
 if (jQuery('#bad-drifting li:has(em)').length > 0) { // There is at least one element
```

otherwise it will always be true, because what jQuery returns is always *truthy*.